# Testing environment for SMS in android

Tags: android, sms

I developed the SMS listener application. I would like to test this app with real device. I don't know how to set up the testing environment. I don't want to use mobile network because it will cost. I would like to know is there the online service for it.

Thanks

Comment: Well, install the app on your phone and wait for someone to send you an SMS. Oh, hang on! You can send SMS to yourself too!

Comment: If I will write my answer then How can you hear it ? On StackOverflow hearing facility is not available !!!

Comment: @Swayam could you pls recommend me some app? I don't want the app which use mobile network cos it will charge me a lot for testing.

Comment: In that case, the best thing is to use the emulator as mentioned in the answer. Or use some website which allows you to send SMS for free.

Comment: oh I see. My question is worth -4. :)

Answer (score 4):

If you want to test on the emulator, you can use `telnet`

```
telnet localhost 5554

sms send <any fake number> this is the message
```

Comment: Or better yet, use the built-in SMS sender inside DDMS -> Emulator Control :-)

Comment: @Darwind yep you could do that as well. But I love terminal and hate mouse, lol

Comment: True, but switching between different applications, I hate the most :P

Comment: @ThaiTran I want to test on real devices.